# (Android) ¿Cómo ejecutar una acción al llegar tal fecha?

Tags: android

Quería saber cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute una acción al llegar una determinada fecha en Android. En mi caso, me gustaría que se creara en firebase una entrada al llegar el día 1 de cada mes. No pongo código porque no tengo nada, a pesar de haber estado investigando por internet. Gracias y siento la falta de código.

Comment: Esto le podría dar una idea de como comenzar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28017943/8933039

Comment: Paco [este código hace `beep` cada 10 segundos](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService). está basado en `ScheduledExecutorService`. Creo que es lo que necesitas. En lugar de los 10 segundos, le pones la fecha que deseas. Solamente ten en cuenta esto que dice la doc: *Todos los métodos de programación aceptan retrasos y períodos relativos como argumentos, no como horas o fechas absolutas. Es muy simple transformar un tiempo absoluto representado como una Fecha en la forma requerida...*

Comment: ...  *Por ejemplo, para programar en una fecha futura determinada, puede usar: **`schedule (task, date.getTime () - System.currentTimeMillis (), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).`***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BROADCAST RECEIVER.
Broadcast Receiver es un componente de una app que recive eventos ocurridos en el sistema, por ejemplo uno de esos eventos podría ser.. que la batería se está agotando, que se ha activado el GPS, que la fecha ha cambiado (esto te interesa), etc.

Entonces, para poder recibir dichas notificaciones del sistema debemos hacer dos cosas:

1. Crear una subclase de la clase BroadCastReceiver e implementar el método onReceive() que recibirá un Intent a través del cual se puede conocer que tipo de notificación hemos recibido. Por ejemplo, esto es un receptor que avisa cuando se ha recibido un SMS.

```
public class Receptor extends BroadcastReceiver{
  private final String NOTIFICACION_SMS = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
  if(NOTIFICACION_SMS.equals(intent.getAction()){
     Toast.makeText(context, "Recibido SMS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}

}
```

2. Registrar la subclase en el fichero `Manifest` de manera que indicamos que será la candidata a recibir ciertas notificaciones, mediante la etiqueta `receiver` establecemos un filtro de intent con la acción que se espera recibir, no olvidemos que algunas acciones requieren permisos de usuario, en concreto este ejmplo del SMS tendría esta pinta en el fichero `Manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<application ...
  <receiver android:name=".Receptor">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
</application>
```

Este tipo de app no requiere ni siquiera de un ActivityMain (pero añádelo en tus primeras versiones para que veas como funciona), pero en las nuevas versiones de android es necesario que el usuario haya iniciado la app voluntariamente para evitar apps maliciosas que se aprovechen de esto.
Busca el BroadcastReceiver que más se ajuste a tu necesidad e implementalo debidamente.